# ASP.Net Core 3.1 API hosted with Systemd on Ubuntu: configuration keys always NULL

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, key, systemd, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a ASP.Net Core 3.1 API, which I try to host within systemd under Ubuntu. I added the NuGet packages Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Systemd to the project, and used the .Usesystemd() function within the program.cs file as expected. Moreover, I created a self-contained service using the command line to publish the API:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r linux-x64 --self-contained
```

The publish folder was copied into the Ubuntu system, and I created the service file 'mytest.service' which lies within the /etc/systemd/system directory:

```
[Unit]
Description=My test API

[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStart=/home/myuser/Desktop/Release/netcoreapp3.1/linux-x64/publish/MyTestApi

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then I reloaded the daemon conf using the command line:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

And I tried to start the service which started correctly:

```
sudo systemctl start mytest.service
```

And the status shows me that the service is running:

```
sudo systemctl status mytest.service
```

● mytest.service - My test API
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mytest.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-11-09 14:15:21 CET; 1min 32s ago
Main PID: 4212 (MyTestApi)
Tasks: 23 (limit: 18915)
Memory: 271.4M
CGroup: /system.slice/mytest.service
└─4212 /home/myuser/Desktop/Release/netcoreapp3.1/linux-x64/publish/MyTestApi

nov. 09 14:15:19 HP-All-in-One-27-xa0xxx systemd[1]: Starting My Test API...
nov. 09 14:15:21 HP-All-in-One-27-xa0xxx systemd[1]: Started My Test API.

But the problem is that the configuration keys which are into the appsettings.json file have a NULL value:

```
{
     "MyKey": "MyKeyValue",
     "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*"
```

}

The retrieved value of the key "MyKey" is NULL, but I do not understand why?
If I launch directly the MyTest file from the command line, every thing is fine and the value is retrieved correctly.

What did I do wrong, and has anybody experienced the same problem before?
Thanks for any suggestions or ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what was causing the problem: I needed to add the working directory to the service file, which now looks like the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=My test API

[Service]
Type=notify
WorkingDirectory=/home/myuser/Desktop/Release/netcoreapp3.1/linux-x64/publish
ExecStart=/home/myuser/Desktop/Release/netcoreapp3.1/linux-x64/publish
/MyTestApi

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And now the appsettings.json key values are correctly retrieved.

Thanks